# Dynamic matrix in c/c++ - peculiar error

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I was trying to write a small program with a dynamical matrix ( I started it in C, but now I see I need to do it in C++). the main part of it looked like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j,k;
    printf("Matrix A n x m:\n");
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input m: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int** matrix = new int*[m]; 

    if (matrix == NULL) {
        printf("no memory\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(k=0; k<m; ++k)
    {
        matrix[k]=new int[n];

        if(matrix[k]==NULL)
        {
        printf("error");
        }    
    }    

    j=0;

    do
    {
        i=0;
        do
        {
            printf("input (%d,%d):", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
            i++;
        }   
        while (i<n); 
    j++;
    }    
    while (j<m);
}
```

It compiles with no error, but it doesn't work properly. For example, I can create 2x4 matrix, but no 4x2. After The Input (3,0) message appears, the program crashes. Why?

Comment: have you tried to use some debugger?

Comment: C++ version in a nutshell: don't use pointers, do use `<iostream>`.

Comment: @chris What makes you think `printf`/`scanf` is any part of his problem?

Comment: @MattPhillips, I never said it was, but those are a lot more prone to errors. The OP said they need to do it in C++, and C IO isn't the only (and quite frankly the best in the general case) solution.

Answer (score 1):

you mixed between i and j, you should do `scanf("%d", &matrix[j][i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Your i and j values are the wrong way round.  j goes from 0..m-1, i goes from 0..n-1.  Your input should be fore &matrix[j][i].  Either that or change the while loops to i < m and j < n.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it an array must have at least 1 element, if you are compiling in strict ANSI mode.

```
int m[];          /*ILLEGAL*/
int m[0];        /* definition of 0 size -- ILLEGAL */
```

please correct me if I am incorrect

You must declare the array element to have (at least) one element if you are compiling in strict ANSI mode

kind regards

Comment: `int m[0];` is legal, and anyway what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Hmm,http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/errarray0len_xml.html

Comment: Dude I have only just joined, give me a chance to get to grips with how this all works.  I hadnt finished answering ;)

Comment: `int m[]` is not illegal, this is just an address constant (eg. as a actual function argument) => `int myproc(int m[], in count) { ... `

Comment: @rubberboots, I'm pretty darn sure it is illegal. If you mean it's a pointer, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: I shall endevaour to make sure I answer completely and double check it before I post.  My bad. Thanks

Comment: @rubberboots, In that context, it is equivalent to a pointer. That's not a declaration, though, like in the answer.

Comment: Maybe its getting a little too late and I should be in bed.  Its been a few years since I have tackled C. :)

Comment: @Anthony_SB - something to chew on in bed: these are both legal: `char ray[] = { 1 };         /* LEGAL */
 char x = 0[ray];            /* LEGAL */`